# Using Least Squares to get the 'input'

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-analysis

I would like to solve the system of equations $$Ax=B$$ for $x$. However, unlike almost every tutorial on the internet, I do NOT want the coefficients of the operator $A$ - rather I want the actual inputs $x$. To be specific, let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    3& 5x & 6x^2 & 7sin(x)
\end{bmatrix}$$
(Where there will be as many rows as there are measurements or inputs)
I know how to get the vector $\beta=\begin{bmatrix}1& 5 & 6 & 7\end{bmatrix}$, that is simply $\beta=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$. But how can I use Least Squares to get $x$ given the form of $A$ and the output $B$? (If this is nonlinear, you can drop the last two terms in $A$)

Comment: So you want, given a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 5x_1 & 6x_1^2 & 7\sin x_1\\3 & 5x_2 & 6x_2^2 & 7\sin x_3\\3 & 5x_3 & 6x_3^2 & 7\sin x_3\\3 & 5x_4 & 6x_4^2 & 7\sin x_4\end{bmatrix}$, to find the values $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$?

Comment: Yes! Assuming you have the output.

Comment: Why do you need the output? Can't you just divide the $5x_1, 5x_2, \dots$ column by $5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the example we have

$$
\epsilon^2(x) = \Vert A(x) x-B\Vert^2 = 111 - 6 x - 41 x^2 - 72 x^3 + 25 x^4 + 36 x^6 - 98 x \sin(x) + 49 x^2 \sin^2(x)
$$

and then

$$
x = \arg \min_x \epsilon^2(x) = 1.00885
$$

If you have instead

$$
x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)
$$

$$
A(x) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
3 & 5 x_1 & 6x_1^2& 7\sin x_1 \\
3 & 5 x_2 & 6x_2^2& 7\sin x_2 \\
3 & 5 x_3 & 6x_3^2& 7\sin x_3 \\
3 & 5 x_4 & 6x_4^2& 7\sin x_4
\end{array}
\right)
$$

then

$$
\epsilon^2(x) = \Vert A(x) x-B\Vert^2
$$

and

$$
x = \arg \min_x \epsilon^2(x) = (0.0925942,\ 0.516572,\ 0.608943,\ 0.697946)
$$

with a RMSE of $\epsilon \approx 1.88411\times10^{-15}$

The $\epsilon^2(x)$ minimization should follow a Newton-Raphson like procedure.

Comment: Interesting. Can we write this in a closed matrix form? I am trying to understand how this compares to the $\beta=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$ case.

Comment: if I understood correctly, this problem is non-linear and it will be difficult to obtain a closed formula to represent its solution. It will have to be solved through an iterative process like Newton-Raphson's algorithm family.

Comment: How about I remove the last two nonlinear terms and only keep the '3' and '5x' linear terms. Can it be done now?

Comment: Note that $A(x)x$ is still nonlinear (quadratic). If $A$ does not depends on $x$ a closed formula like the one you suggested is possible.